# Installing Bash Commands on Microcore Linux

Tags: linux

I've set up a virtual box with Microcore Linux just for fun, but I can't seem to get any bash commands working. I'd like to have access to certain commands like `tree`. I've installed the bash package using the Tinycore package manager but it's not working. How do I set up all the basic bash commands?

I can't install `tree` using `tce-load` as comments have stated.
[image]

Comment: They are not `bash` commands.

Comment: [`tce-load -iw tree`](http://forum.tinycorelinux.net/index.php?topic=4017.0)

Comment: error 404 no such file or directory